# JQuery, div displayed but does not fade

Tags: jquery, html

I'm a newbie here and trying to run my first jQuery program. The code works fine on JsFiddle, however - when I try to run it in my browser the div is displayed but it won't fade. Can you please help? Am i referencing the jQuery libraries correctly? I have also create separate files for html, css and script in the same folder. Thanks in advance.

HTML file -

```
<head>
    <title>Result</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
    <script type='text/javascript' language='Javascript' ``src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div></div>   
</body>
```

Sylesheet -

```
div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #FA6900;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

and the script -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').click(function() {
        $('div').fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: You have referenced the jQuery UI, but not jQuery itself.  Please visit https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

Comment: What are those two backticks  in the HTML script include?

Comment: Note (for after you fix the current problem by including jquery.js instead of jquery-ui.js): `$('div').fadeOut('slow');` would fade out _all_ div elements on the page, you probably want `$(this).fadeOut('slow');` to fade just the clicked item.

Comment: please include the fiddle.

Comment: include jquery library before use it dependicies

Comment: Changed the libraries to http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js. Also removed div and added this. The div still won't fade. Do I need to install something? It works simply fine on JsFiddle.

Comment: @SuperScript the two backticks were by mistake when i was trying to intend and post here. I removed them as well.

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks, I think i should use the 'this' keyword more often. But i guess i just have one div on my page as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ExASAjU/2/edit) (It works fine)

You have to link to jQuery library, like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks aldanux. I literally copy and pasted the entire code. The div is displayed but it won;t fade! I tried it on Chrome, Firefox and IE as well - same problem. Do you i need to install something?

Comment: The link "Demo" above don`t work for you? Have you another library in your file?

Comment: Nope. No this the only line referencing the library -

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Finally i managed to get it run. I was simply missing to the src="script.js" in my <script></script> tags :)